# Individual Hard Disk Power management under WS2008R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, electrical-power

Are Hard Disks are controlled individually under WS2008R2? meaning one HD is running 24/7 with database requests while another is spun down after 20mins until the automated monthly backup occurs.

Neither of these links mentions this:
http://aps2.toshiba-tro.de/kb0/HTD84026Q0000R01.htm
http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2008/03/17/managing-power-with-group-policy-part-1-of-3.aspx

Anyone tried [hdparm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hdparm) (a command line utility for getting/setting various HD parameters) on WS2008R2?
The real question is; does a wake up command get issued to ALL drives, or just the drive that is required at that moment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that

A) yes, drives are controlled individually; while I don't have direct experience with WS2008R2, Win7 does stop rotating individual drives; and

B) wake commands are drive-specific.

This assumes that your system can see the individual drives (ie they are not hidden in an aggregate like a RAID controller) and that the drives really are idle.  Any activity that can't be satisfied from cache (which means any write) will require the drive to be spinning.

Comment: How can you easily tell if a drive (not RAID) is sleeping?